# Operations on binary numbers, that have equal numbers of two available digits, that preserve this property?

Tags: functions, binary, decimal-expansion

I'm looking for operations on binary numbers that have the same number of the available digits, $0$ and $1$, such as $100011$, $100101$ and $10$. These could be integers as the examples given are, or restricted, for example to specific rational ranges.

That preserve this quality, so that the $1$'s count is still equal to the $0$'s count.

Can an example be given?

I'm interested in this for possible compute applications, however this question as posed seems a better fit for maths.SE.

Comment: Well, $x\to 4x+1$ comes to mind for integer numbers, as it simply adds $01$ at the right of $x$. But I think many more examples can be given. What kind of operations are allowed?

Comment: I think any more example that can be given would boil down to the case that you have mentioned.

Comment: Any sort of function/operation, simple ones with nifty results are best, thanks for that one, the consequences are a bit trivial though. I imagined something that was unfortunately also a bit simple, based on your approach, transforming this example $1001$ (ignore the hyphen) into $1001$-$1001$.

Comment: Since you do not want a bijection on the set of binary numbers here is a possible solution.
Multiply the number x by 10/x where x is not equal to 0, the operation yields 1.
x is the decimal forms of the binary number.
Obviously many such operations can be figured out.                                        though i think that @Aretino 's example is nicer than this one.